# Android nohistory not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've made a preferences activity as the following:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Preferences"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:label="@string/set_preferences">
    </activity>
```

Inside that activity, there is a bottom that launches a site on the browser. Pressing that bottom and then "back" does return to that Preferences menu. Why?

Comment: If possible please share your code for button action

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @chrispy I don't remember, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Code added to Manifest file is fine. Try this code for button action it works.

```
   public void buttonClick(View v){
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }
```

Comment: MRP thank you, sorry for the delay. I have no access to the work right now, will update as soon as I do.